# Cleaning text files with regex of python

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I have a huge file where there lines like this one:

"**En g茅n茅ral un tr猫s bon hotel       La terrasse du bar pr猫s du lobby**"

How to remove these Sinographic characters from the lines of the file so I get a new file where these lines are with Roman alphabet characters only?
I was thinking of using regular expressions.
Is there a character class for all Roman alphabet characters, e.g. Arabic numerals, a-nA-N and other(punctuation)?

Comment: You can use hex values between a certain range? Perhaps anything up to 0x7F? It depends on what you're calling "normal"...

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to specify "every allowed symbol" with some sort of regex like [-a-zA-Z0-9!"£$%^&*(){}[\]\|,./<>?;'#:@~`] or whatever, but then your code will look horribly ugly and may miss something out!

Comment: What encoding are you using when reading this file?

Comment: @ Mike Samuel I'm using utf-8. `codecs.open(file,'r','utf-8')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`string`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module.

```
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.digits
'0123456789'
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>>
```

And it seems the code you want to replace is Chinese. If you all your string is unicode, you can use the simple range `[\u4e00-\u9fa5]` to replace them. This is not the whole range of Chinese but enough.

```
>>> s = u"En g茅n茅ral un tr猫s bon hotel La terrasse du bar pr猫s du lobby"
>>> s
u'En g\u8305n\u8305ral un tr\u732bs bon hotel La terrasse du bar pr\u732bs du lobby'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(ur'[\u4e00-\u9fa5]', '', s)
u'En gnral un trs bon hotel La terrasse du bar prs du lobby'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

I find this [regex cheet sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) to come in very handy for situations like these.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8
import re
import string

u = u"En.!?+ 123 g茅n茅ral un tr猫s bon hotel La terrasse du bar pr猫s du lobby"
p = re.compile(r"[^\w\s\d{}]".format(re.escape(string.punctuation)))
for m in p.finditer(u):
    print m.group()

>>> 茅
>>> 茅
>>> 猫
>>> 猫
```

I'm also a huge fan of the [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) module.

```
from unidecode import unidecode

u = u"En.!?+ 123 g茅n茅ral un tr猫s bon hotel La terrasse du bar pr猫s du lobby"

print unidecode(u)

>>> En.!?+ 123 gMao nMao ral un trMao s bon hotel La terrasse du bar prMao s du lobby
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regexes.

To keep only ascii characters:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unicodedata

unistr = u"En g茅n茅ral un tr猫s bon hotel La terrasse du bar pr猫s du lobby"
unistr = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', unistr) # to preserve `e` in `é`
ascii_bytes = unistr.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

To remove everything except ascii letters, numbers, punctuation:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation, whitespace

to_keep = set(map(ord, ascii_letters + digits + punctuation + whitespace))
all_bytes = range(0x100)
to_remove = bytearray(b for b in all_bytes if b not in to_keep)
text = ascii_bytes.translate(None, to_remove).decode()
# -> En gnral un trs bon hotel La terrasse du bar prs du lobby
```